# input radio buttons/stars wont center

Tags: css

I have 5 stars that I can't get to center, I tried `text-align: center; margin: auto`, not working. It only works without the css? Please see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/6TGF4/

What are preventing it from centering them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had to change a few attributes, check [this updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/6TGF4/11/).

I removed the float and text align then gave the correct `margin: 0 auto;` to center the stars.

Comment: just to add in this solution (that I agree), that the container, in this case the `span`, needs a fixed width to work with `margin:0 auto;`

Comment: sorry, it's a `div` not a `span` :)

Answer (score 1):

> What are preventing it from centering them?

The `float: left` (obviously) and the `display: block`. The easiest way to achieve this would be `display: inline`, but then you can't set a fixed width and height any more - you may have to fiddle with margins / paddings to achieve what you want then.

Comment: i tried remove the float: left it still keep being on the left

Answer (score 1):

Try the update version. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6TGF4/17/). It should be center align now.